# Is there a cleaner way of writing this jQuery?

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop

Could I write this into a loop?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slideItems1').bxSlider();
    $('#slideItems2').bxSlider();
    $('#slideItems3').bxSlider();
    $('#slideItems4').bxSlider();
    $('#slideItems5').bxSlider();
});
```

I am using [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) and for using multiple galleries you need to call the slider and associate it to each item. I have over 200 products sometimes per page.

Comment: I also highly recommend that gallery to. Very minimal and slick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use an [attribute starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to select all elements with an ID that starts with "slideItems":

```
$('[id^="slideItems"]').bxSlider();
```

This is the case with the majority of jQuery methods (and most plugins will allow it too). The method is applied to every element in the matched set, so there's no need for a loop. You can see how the plugin you're using implements this functionality [in its source](https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider/blob/1324b6eb39f07d9a3112fe564c94becafaafbbca/source/jquery.bxSlider.js#L1253) (notice the call to `each`, and note that `this` refers to the jQuery object containing the matched set of elements):

```
this.each(function(){
    // make sure the element has children
    if($(this).children().length > 0){
        base.initShow();
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd try and specify the element type as part of that to improve the specificity of the selector

Comment: @CaffGeek - Why? It's selecting based on `id` values, which are unique in the document. They are as specific as you should ever need to get.

Comment: Plus its not like these ids will appear randomly through out dom.

Comment: Performance.  They're specific to us as we quickly see only a few will match, however, the selector engine has to look at the id of EVERY element in the DOM.  If you add the element to the selector like, `$('div[id^="slideItems"]').bxSlider();`, then it only has to look at the `div`s (replace div with whatever element it actually is).  Basically it can use the native getElementsByClassName to reduce the list of elements to check initially.

Comment: @CaffGeek - In the real world the difference is going to be insignificant. In the majority of browsers `querySelectorAll` will be used for both, and will be pretty much the same speed in both cases. You're right though - if performance at that level is a real concern, it would be better to add the tag name.

Comment: There's still too much IE7 out there for me to rely on querySelectorAll

Answer (score 6):

Give all your slide items a class and then just do `$('.slideItem').bxSlider();`

Comment: This did not work. I did `class="element"  id="slideItems1"` etc for each one and did this and just crashed the page

Comment: @user1686277 - If you use this then you need to give each element a class name of "slideItem". You will no longer need the `id`.

Answer (score 3):

Give all the elements a class, then select them using that class.

```
$('.slideItems').bxSlider();
```

Answer (score 2):

The short but not optimal rewrite would be (if the list of slideitems is fixed)

```
$(function(){
    $('#slideItems1, #slideItems2, #slideItems3, #slideItems4, #slideItems5').bxSlider();
});
```

however I would highly recommend simply to give them all a class. Say `slideritem` and do

```
$(function(){
    $('.slideritem').bxSlider();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that give the class name for that and access that using class name.

```
//slideritem is class name which you give to all which has to slider div

$(function()
{

    $('.slideritem').bxSlider();
});
```